How to fix invalid ELF header in bcrypt docker
FROM node:18 AS build
WORKDIR /app
Copy only package.json and package-lock.json first
COPY package*.json ./
Install system dependencies for bcrypt to compile
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential python3
Install dependencies fresh inside the container
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
Rebuild bcrypt to ensure compatibility with the container's environment
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
Dynamically set the environment-specific script to run
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run ${NODE_ENV}"].
.dockerignore: node_modules, npm-debug.log, .env. .DS_Store.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
frontend:
build:
context: ./dashboardclient
dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
- '3000:80'
networks:
- app-network
depends_on:
- backend
volumes:
- ./src:/app/src
- /app/node_modules
environment:
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'
command: npm start
backend:
build:
context: ./backend
dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
- '5000:5000'
networks:
- app-network
volumes:
- ./backend:/app
- /usr/src/app/node_modules
environment:
- NODE_ENV=dev
networks:
app-network:
driver: bridge

Your volumes: are overwriting everything in the image with content from the host machine plus a stale version of your library tree.  Does deleting both volumes: blocks help?
